# Is `thiserror` impossible to use in stable Rust?

Tags: rust, thiserror

Using a dependency like

```
eframe = "0.20.1"
```

I'm running into compilation errors because of it's dependency

```
Compiling thiserror v1.0.38
lib.rs
`#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
```

It is because of this line:

```
#![cfg_attr(provide_any, feature(provide_any))]
```

Shouldn't be Rust crates compilable on stable channel?

I know this can be easily solved by switching to nightly build.
But if I can, I'd rather be on stable.

Comment: Remove the `target` folder.

Comment: See: https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror/issues/192